# move_uploaded_file for different input files

Tags: php

the method I have is I create three input files which will be posted to three different column in database table.

Heres my parameter:

```
$additional_comments=$_POST['additional_comments']; 
$image_one = $_FILES['image_one']['type'];
$image_two = $_FILES['image_two']['type'];
$image_three = $_FILES['image_three']['type'];

    if($image=="image/jpeg" || $image=="image/jpg" || $image=="image/gif" || $image=="image/png") 
        {           
            $gambar_satu        = $foldername . basename($_FILES['image_one']['name']);  
            $gambar_dua         = $foldername . basename($_FILES['image_two']['name']);  
            $gambar_tiga        = $foldername . basename($_FILES['image_three']['name']);  

                if  (   move_uploaded_file 
                            ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $gambar_satu) 
                            ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $gambar_dua) 
                            ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $gambar_tiga) 
                    ) 

                    {
                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare
                            ("INSERT INTO table...
```

In the `if (move_uploaded_file...` I am trying to insert three paramater there which they are `$gambar_satu`, `$gambar_dua`, `$gambar_tiga`.

My question is how is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from the [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) website

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
 }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But no, it doesn't help.

Comment: Hi alisa, if you are considering the multiple files for a single purpose, you can use <input type="file" name="img" multiple> multiple attribute in the file input with the posted code. However if you are considering different names for file input, then you will have to use move_uploaded_file multiple times with the respective parameters. By the way did SSL ajax work that day?

Comment: Can you please describe your problem?

Comment: The problem is not only the multiple images, but also these picture will be posted to difference column name:  _I create three input files which will be posted to three different column in database table._

Comment: So you want to push the images in the database right? OK I would recommend saving only the relative path of the image on the database [use move_uploaded_file to save to a location and save the path in the DB] not saving the entire the image file in the database as it would lead to abnormal increase in the database size. Also if the file gets corrupted in the database, it is very painful to recover from it.

Comment: Yes, that is I am doing now.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing alisa?

Comment: I skip the yahoo a moment. I will finish what I can finish now.